# Problem setting default download directory in Watir after update

Tags: ruby, watir

We recently updated our Watir version from 6.8 to 6.19 in anticipation of the 7.0 beta. Since then, our browser configuration that sets the default directory for chrome has stopped working. Our method that sets it is below.

```
    def setup

      prefs = {
        download: {
          prompt_for_download: false,
          default_directory: @download_dir
        }
      }

      Watir::Browser.new :chrome, options: { prefs: prefs }
    end
```

@download_dir is set as the dir that I want and I have confirmed that by checking the value with a breakpoint after prefs has been defined.

As far as I can tell, this is how http://watir.com/guides/chrome/ specifies that you should set this up. This method worked fine before the update. I've tried some of the solutions from similar issues on SO with no success.

I receive no errors as far as I can tell, and our testing suite runs fine other than downloading to the chrome default folder instead.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you change the Selenium-WebDriver version too? The current version of Selenium has a bug with Symbols. Switching to Strings - eg `"prompt_for_download" => false` should fix the problem.

Comment: The bug I was referring to was https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7917.

Comment: This was it, thanks so much! I'll add an answer for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is due to a bug in selenium detailed here github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7917.

Using strings in the style of `"prompt_for_download" => false` fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried using `"prompt_for_download"` as a string as well as all other inputs but that did not work.

Changing a driver directly worked for me though:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, options: { prefs: prefs })
browser.driver.download_path = downloads_path
```

where `downloads_path` represents the custom directory you want to set.